# SVG images displayed as broken images on server

Tags: html, svg

I'm encountering an odd problem showing .svg using simple img tags on Apache.

On my local computer, the images are visible. On my mt VPS, the images come across as broken links. When I right click on a broken image link and 'Open Image', it shows the images correctly (telling me that the path is correct).

My HTML looks like this:

```
<img width="32" height="32" alt="icon" id="create-wheel-icon2" src="public/assets/img/svg/idea_vect.svg" style="left: 230px; top: 57px; opacity: 1;">
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The info in link that Robert provided above worked for me:

.htaccess file with these rules:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Answer (score 9):

Most likely you aren't serving the images with the correct mime type. There's some information on how to do that here: http://kaioa.com/node/45

You could always try to get a png file to work first to make sure it isn't something obvious about where you are putting the images.

Comment: The svg mimetype has been part of the default config in apache since 2007 or so.

Comment: Thanks so much. That link helped get SVG's serving on a Rackspace cloud site.